# How to perform DFT+GW using a small number of points around high symmetry points?

Tags: band-structure

I need to work out optical properties of TMDC-based structures. For this I need to get DFT+GW bandstructure around G (Г), K, Q (lambda) points. I tried to use BerkeleyGW for this, but it is too heavy computation for my laptop. But I need just a small set of points with GW corrections (let's say 5-10 around G, K, Q) so I don't actually need to recalculate the whole BZ. It is completely not obvious though how to customize any of the methods known to me to do this. Are there any solutions? I am not restricted by just BerkeleyGW and can try do any package on any system (Mac is preferable).

Comment: [Quantum ESPRESSO](https://www.quantum-espresso.org) has pw4gww.x and gww.x: [see this tutorial](https://www.quantum-espresso.org/tutorials/shanghai-2013/hands-on-gw/). Also, from this [OpenAtom tutorial](https://charm.cs.illinois.edu/OpenAtom/GWDoc/gw_documentation.html) and this [Yambo tutorial](https://www.yambo-code.eu/wiki/index.php?title=GW_tutorial._Convergence_and_approximations_(BN)) - it looks like these packages can also specify specific k-points which addresses your concern.

Comment: Thank you very much for your links! I will be happy to go through all of that options as soon as possible. If you post your comment as an answer, I will upvote it (if I can do this with my rating on the site)

Comment: @AbdulMuhaymin it looks like your comment was helpful, do you think you can expand it into a full answer? This would help remove the question from our unanswered queue!

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but can you update us now that it has been 6+ months since you asked this question? Have you found the answer? Are you still actively in need of an answer? If @AbdulMuhaymin can answer it, then that's great, but if not it would be helpful for you to let us know whether or not you are still actively in need of an answer :)